# modify output from 1 query

Tags: sql, oracle, jsp

need Your suggestion Guy's. I don't know what the title of my question. but I has 1 query which give an ouput like this picture :
[image: output Query]

> and this is my query :

```
select to_char(aa.DATE_AWAL, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi') DATE_AWAL, to_char(aa.DATE_AKHIR, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi') DATE_AKHIR,
to_char(aa.DATE_AWAL, 'hh24:mi') TIME_AWAL, to_char(aa.DATE_AKHIR, 'hh24:mi') TIME_AKHIR,
 cc.NAMARUANG,aa.IDMEETING from TMEETING_ROOM aa 
inner join MMEETING_TYPE bb on aa.IDTYPE=bb.IDMEETING 
inner join MMEETING_ROOM cc on aa.IDMEETINGROOM = cc.IDMEETINGROOM 
inner join HR.VWKARYAWAN dd on aa.IDPENGUSUL=dd.IDKARYAWAN 
inner join HR.MLOKASI ee on aa.IDLOKASI = ee.IDLOKASI 
where aa.IS_DELETE IS NULL 
and aa.IDCANCEL IS NULL 
and (
wm_overlaps ( 
wm_period(aa.DATE_AWAL, aa.DATE_AKHIR),
wm_period(
TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(trunc(sysdate) + 08/24, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi'), 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi'), 
TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(trunc(sysdate) + 23/24, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi'), 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi')
)
) = 1
) and aa.idlokasi = 'I' order by cc.NAMARUANG asc, aa.DATE_AWAL asc;
```

Can any body give me suggestion how to make from this query can like this picture: [image: example output]

I'm newbie using oracle SQL

Note: the time and room are dynamic.

Comment: What are you using as the "front-end" e.g. PHP? C#?  it may be far easier to do this "pivot" of the data after SQL has provided the raw data. You certainly are not going to get colour coding from a standard SQL query. Research "**dynamic pivot**"

Comment: by the way, no-one here has time to transcribe from images to get reusable  data; never use images of data, just copy paste and format using the `{}` toolbar button (it just adds 4 chars from the left)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you might achieve a "generic" pivot table in MySQL.

The technique used requires row numbering (and in v8 of MySQL there will be an easier way to do this) but for now it requires using @variables.

Then, with each row number, we "transform" rows to columns using `case expressions` inside he `max()` function (conditional aggregates).

You will need to decide how many columns you need, and note that the order by inside the subquery `t` is vital to successfully arranging the data.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9ee4a7/5)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE YourQueryHere
    (`id` int, `date_column` datetime, `code_column` varchar(7), `data_for_cells1` varchar(5), `data_for_cells2` varchar(5))
;

INSERT INTO YourQueryHere
    (`id`, `date_column`, `code_column`, `data_for_cells1`, `data_for_cells2`)
VALUES
    (1, '2017-11-14 00:00:00', 'Bintang', '09:00', '10:30'),
    (2, '2017-11-14 00:00:00', 'Bintang', '11:00', '12:30'),
    (3, '2017-11-14 00:00:00', 'Bintang', '14:00', '17:00'),
    (4, '2017-11-14 00:00:00', 'Sapporo', '11:30', '14:00'),
    (5, '2017-11-14 00:00:00', 'Sapporo', '14:30', '15:00'),
    (6, '2017-11-14 00:00:00', 'Tiger', '08:00', '09:30'),
    (7, '2017-11-14 00:00:00', 'Tiger', '11:00', '12:00')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select
    code_column
  , max(case when RowNumber = 1 then concat(data_for_cells1, ' ', data_for_cells2) end) as pivcol1
  , max(case when RowNumber = 2 then concat(data_for_cells1, ' ', data_for_cells2) end) as pivcol2
  , max(case when RowNumber = 3 then concat(data_for_cells1, ' ', data_for_cells2) end) as pivcol3
  , max(case when RowNumber = 4 then concat(data_for_cells1, ' ', data_for_cells2) end) as pivcol4
from (
      select * 
           , @counter :=IF(@prev=code_column,@counter+1,1)AS RowNumber
           , @prev := code_column
      from YourQueryHere
      cross join (select @counter:=0, @prev:= '') vars
      order by 
            code_column, date_column
      ) t
group by
    code_column
order by
    code_column

;
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9ee4a7/5/0)**:

```
| code_column |     pivcol1 |     pivcol2 |     pivcol3 | pivcol4 |
|-------------|-------------|-------------|-------------|---------|
|     Bintang | 09:00 10:30 | 11:00 12:30 | 14:00 17:00 |  (null) |
|     Sapporo | 11:30 14:00 | 14:30 15:00 |      (null) |  (null) |
|       Tiger | 08:00 09:30 | 11:00 12:00 |      (null) |  (null) |
```

Comment: you will have to ask a different question. after SQL you have to use something like PHP or C# or Java to process "the front end" and that is - honestly - a different question altogether.

Comment: Sorry late response, I was found the way for the query<br/>
but now I don't know how to create in front-end if using <table>
<br/>
my ouput query was like this :<br/>
thedate||thetime||thetime2|| Room|| start|| end||<br/>
today   || 08.00 || 10.30|| Bintang || 08.30|| 09.00||<br/>
today   || 08.00 || 10.30|| Bintang || 09.00|| 09.30||<br/>
today   || 08.00 || 10.30|| Bintang || 09.30|| 10.00||<br/>
today   || 08.00 || 10.30|| Bintang || 10.00|| 10.30|| <br/> etc.